# Can a human eat the flesh of a sandworm?

Tags: dune

If Fremen ride them, couldn't they also eat them?

There some passages from Kynes about the ecology of Dune that dive deep into the biomechanics of worms, but maybe I am missing something.

Someone that has made the change could feasibly eat a sandworm sandwich and not be poisoned. Alternatively, it could be a vector for the change.

Comment: Obviously a Reverend Mother can eat almost anything since they possess the ability to change the molecular structure of things they eat, but I suspect the acid would burn them horribly before they could do so.

Comment: I’d say getting it would be harder than eating it!

Comment: I don't remember seeing even a single mention of a sandworm recipe or dinner in the Dune series, though Frank Herbert did describe food now and then, e.g., "portyguls."

Comment: Why would being able to ride something mean you can eat it?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is it? They are already drowning sandworms to get the water of life.

Comment: Commercial aircraft. If humans ride them, couldn't they also eat them?

Comment: @AzorAhai Riding a terrible beast indicates control of it. Such control could be used to slaughter it also possibly. Slaughter could be for the purpose of eating. The question as phrased expects you to understand this.

Comment: @DetectiveChimp Just because you can control them doesn't mean they're edible. I'm confused why this is an entailment.

Comment: @AzorAhai wrote, “Just because you can control them doesn’t mean they’re edible.” Thus, the reason for this question.

Comment: @GregSchmit As a matter of fact, a human has eaten an airplane before. Michel Lotito.

Comment: @GregSchmit People have eaten Airplanes before.

Comment: @Möoz citation needed

Comment: @GregSchmit [citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Lotito)

Comment: Damn, I guess that the ability to ride something also implies edibility.

Answer (score 13):

The [*Dune Encyclopedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dune_Encyclopedia) strongly implies that sandworm flesh is inedible and almost certainly poisonous.

> The resulting electrons passed to an electron acceptor believed to be **a cupri-cyanide compound, the reduced form of which accumulated in the worm body.**

and

> Our knowledge of the metabolism of the sandworm is necessarily
>   incomplete, not only because of the size of the creature, but also
>   because of **the presence of many acidic compounds in the worm body.
>   Besides the organic acids, concentrated hydrochloric and sulfuric
>   acids have also been detected.** In some way the living worm buffered
>   itself against these acids, but once the worm died, the body was
>   rapidly digested by them.

While [eating something that contains poisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassava#Potential_toxicity) isn't necessarily impossible, it's hard to imagine what processes you could use to remove cyanide and highly corrosive and toxic acids from the meat before eating it.

Comment: Meh, some baking powder, might do the trick. Also transition metal cyanides aren't necessarily poisonous.

Comment: "transition metal cyanides aren't necessarily poisonous" - Maybe, but [copper cyanide](https://www.nwmissouri.edu/naturalsciences/sds/c/Copper%20I%20cyanide.pdf) is pretty toxic.  Ingesting 100g would be over the LD50 for most people.  Though I guess as long as the worm's flesh is less than 50% copper cyanide by mass (and it probably should be) a person could eat a _modestly sized_ sandworm sandwich and not _necessarily_ die.

Comment: Please note that the Dune Encyclopedia is not canon.

Comment: @MrLister - Canon at the time, then de-canonised by Herbert's talentless son so he could cash in with his own twenty book series based on a post-it note he found on the fridge in his father's house

Comment: @Valorum No no, FH himself said he liked it but he wouldn't let it stand in the way of the real story. In a foreword to the original edition.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109064/20774