Can someone explain the two old people at the ending of "Chapterhouse: Dune"?
In Chapterhouse: Dune who are the two old people at the ending and what are their significance? I understand they are supposedly Face Dancers, but I don't understand why they have been watching Duncan and Sheena from across the universe. What are their motives?

https://neoencyclopedia.fandom.com/wiki/Daniel_and_Marty

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26533/35796

I, and probably mostly everyone who made it to the end of the series, can definitely relate to the plaintive tone of this question.

My take was that the two face dancers were controlling everything all along.  They were treating the Universe as their garden, to tend to.

Can you offer any evidence to back this up?
